# How to stop installing updates in Windows 7 after restart?

Tags: windows-7, shutdown, updates

My Windows 7 started installing updates on shutdown. After I manually forced shutdown by mistake, after restart I have a message : "Installing updates : 10 of 42", i.e. the installation of updates continues. If there is any way to stop the process? Like, start Windows in protected mode or something similar, as it was available in Windows XP? 
I am not asking how to disable automatic updates installation in the future, I am asking how to stop the update process after it has already been started.

Thanks,
Kostya

Comment: This question seams like it belongs on Superuser or similar. http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to kill installing process after it started but just to long press the power button and disable the automatic after restarted.

Answer (score 0):

## SOLUTION !

1) create a **.bat** (**CMD**) file, with this code:

```
sc stop wuauserv
```

2) put that file in STARTUP folder ( **`%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`** )